# why select option value if zero post empty

Tags: php, mysql, select, return-value

I am sorry bad English. I have a select menu option value problem:

```
<select>
   <option value=0>element1</option>
   <option value=1>element2</option> 
</select>
```

I am if select `value="0"` option and this post, it retuns the value with no problem. But, when I use `value = 0` save mysql table, this value not 0 this return empty. This value saving column type integer? What is problem?

I am not using `mysql_real_escape_string` or any filter. If select `value="1"` option no problem, it is saving succesfully.

Thanks

Comment: Almost every browser has a function that you can view HTML, that function is extremely useful when handling form data, use it! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself and what I found was that when posting option/select box values and reading them with PHP, when the 'value' of it was 0 it was acting like I did not post at all because I was checking to see anything had been posted like this:

```
if ($_POST['status']) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

When in fact I needed to check it using `isset()`, because the way shown above returns false even if the value is 0.  The example shown below checks to see if it really is set at all, even if the value is 0.

```
if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

You did not show us your PHP code so I am only guessing this was also your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you missed quotes (")

```
<select name="my_select">
   <option value="0">element1</option>
   <option value="1">element2</option> 
</select> 

<?php 
$my_select_value = $_POST["my_select"];
echo $my_select_value; 
?>
```

Comment: I can't understand your answer. Have not any  my syntax error problem. How must using this.column type integer

Answer (score 0):

This one is a pain...no value is sent in the POST if it's a select and the value is 0....so if it's a POST and NOT sent you can assume the value was 0...

```
if($_POST){
   if(isset($_POST['my_select'])){
      //has a value, can assume it's 1 given the example
   }else {
      //posted, but value wasn't sent, can assume it's 0
   }
}
```